Why do some lenses have the zoom ring reversed?
It isn't a dealbreaker for me, but it is confusing that some lenses have the zoom ring reversed. For instance, my Canon EF zoom lenses all have their lowest focal length on the left and highest on the right, which intuitively makes sense to me. Yet some other lenses I saw on the internet have the lowest on the right and the highest on the left. Is there a reason why some manufacturers reverse the direction, or is it just a random choice?

The "why" is going to depend on the manufactures design.  So I'm not sure we can answer that.

None are reversed. Some rotate counterclockwise to increase focal length and some rotate clockwise to increase focal length. Neither is the "correct" direction and neither is the "incorrect" direction. Neither is "standard" and neither is "reversed".
Nikon has pretty much always been the opposite direction from Canon. They were the two largest players in the 135 format for decades. Third party lens maker Sigma is the same direction as Canon, third party lens maker Tamron is the same direction as Nikon.
For what it's worth, manual focus rings are the same way: Canon's rotate clockwise towards infinity and counterclockwise towards minimum focus distance (MFD). Nikon's rotate counterclockwise towards infinity and clockwise toward MFD. Again, Sigma is the same as Canon, Tamron is the same as Nikon. Most lenses I'm aware of do tend to have infinity focus and maximum focal length in common in the same direction, and MFD and minimum focal length in common in the opposite direction.

In a free market there must be an extraordinary incentive to standardize anything as unimportant as direction of zoom rotation. Manufacturers agreeing on standard ring rotation direction on their own is less likely than aliens.
More specifically, you can either have high focal length with the "right" rotation or markings from lowest to longest from the left to right but not both.
